# How can i know the network loss between two clients while on going audio call in webRTC ios

Tags: ios, webrtc

How to identify the network loss between two clients (Any one side) when using the webRTC audio call in IOS ? In android identify using onPeerConnectionError.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is:

```
/** Called any time the IceConnectionState changes. */
- (void)peerConnection:(RTCPeerConnection *)__unused peerConnection didChangeIceConnectionState:(RTCIceConnectionState)newState {

    /*
     * RTCIceConnectionStateNew,
     * RTCIceConnectionStateChecking,
     * RTCIceConnectionStateConnected,
     * RTCIceConnectionStateCompleted,
     * RTCIceConnectionStateFailed,
     * RTCIceConnectionStateDisconnected,
     * RTCIceConnectionStateClosed,
     * RTCIceConnectionStateCount,
     */
}
```

which is implemented in **RTCPeerConnectionDelegate**

https://github.com/otalk/webrtc-ios/blob/master/include/RTCPeerConnectionDelegate.h#L59